# Decrease interval of TomcatDeployer

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

How can I decrease the interval with which the [TomcatDeployer](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/web/tomcat/tc5/TomcatDeployer.html) is scanning for new artifacts? I'm using JBoss 4.2.3.

Comment: Did my answer help? Is that what you were after?

Comment: @CoolBeans `ScanPeriod` was already at `5000`. :-(

Comment: that means it was at 5 seconds. So you want it to scan quicker than that?

Comment: @CoolBeans It feels like it's 60 seconds or more, instead of 5.

Comment: where are these artifacts located in your jboss instance? Are they under the <server_instance>/deploy folder?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are deploying your artifacts in JBoss, you are most likely asking about the hot deployment scan frequency.

In JBossAS 4.2, I believe you set the hot deployment scan frequency in the `server/$instance_name/conf/jboss-service.xml` file for the `DeploymentScanner` MBean:

```
 <!-- this is in milli-seconds, so 60000 ms means 60 seconds which is scanning every minute in the deploy folder for changes in the deployed packages -->
  <attribute name="ScanPeriod">60000</attribute>
  <attribute name="ScanEnabled">true</attribute>
```